# Cannot delete in EF4

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am trying to delete an "AttendeeEvent" from the database with EF4, however I am getting the following error:-

The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

My code is as follows :-

```
        public void UnRegisterCurrentUserForEvent(int eventId)
    {
        Attendee attendee = GetOrCreateAttendeeForCurrentUser();
        AttendeeEvent av = attendee.AttendeeEvents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EventID == eventId);

        if(av != null)
        {
            attendee.AttendeeEvents.Remove(av);
        }

        this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I tried to change the End 2 On Delete from the properties in the .edmx however when I set to cascade, I am getting an error:-

Error   1   Error 132: cannot have operation specified since its multiplicity is '*'. Operations cannot be specified on ends with multiplicity '*'

Can you guys help me out

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Do you have a cascade in the DB? Did you have it when you created your model? Sounds like you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only removing the `AttendeeEvent` from the collection of attendee events for an `Attendee`. So suppose you have an attendee `A` and event `AV` and you remove `AV` from `A`. What should happen inside the database? You haven't actually removed `AV`. You've only said that `A` should no longer be related to `AV`. So inside your database, the foreign key from `AV` to `A` is set to NULL, which is not allowed by your database model.

The fix is simple: replace the line where you remove the event from the attendee with the following line:

```
this.ObjectContext.AttendeeEvents.DeleteObject(av);
```